# Who should be the people from whom the letters of recommendation should be taken for a PhD application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter, international-students

When applying for PhD programs in the US, as an international student, typically 3 letters of recommendation are required.

The exact question that I want to ask is that if it is possible for all the three letters to be written by professors in the institute where I did my undergrad from.

Comment: Of course it's possible, if those professors agree. Perhaps you mean *is it a good idea?* and the answer to that is yes, if those are the people who know you and your work best.

Comment: To extend what others have said (thus far), most every U.S. applicant will have had ONLY undergraduate professors, so not only is it possible, it is likely the case for the majority of applicants (vast majority of applicants for some fields, such as Education and English literature). However, if you've done some graduate work, and especially if you've completed a graduate degree, it would probably be expected that at least one (and probably two if you completed a graduate degree) of the recommendations be from your graduate work teachers, but it's certainly not *required*.

Answer (score 1):

Usually they are professors you have had contact from your undergraduate or Master's studies.
You most likely wrote a thesis at the end of your previous degree, so the supervisor(s) of your thesis is(are) a good choice to ask recommendations from.
If you need more letters, and you didn't have any other research experience in another lab, then you could possibly ask professors in whose lectures you took an excellent grade.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the people you take recommendation letters from are usually your Professors from your undergrad program.
Contact those professors who have a good reputation in their particular research field. Collecting three letters could be a task, so look for professors with whom you have worked as a student, secured a good grade in their subject, and you can always ask the department/institute head to provide a letter. I would recommend you contact such professors who know you well about your potential in the academia and research field. If you know such professors from your undergrad on a personal level, it will make your task easier.
Best,
M